# How to play .aac file in Cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

How can play an `.aac` file in Cocos2d?

Answer (score 1):

Use CocosDenshion. However, you may want to convert your audio files to AAC encoded *.caf format, as that is the preferred format.

```
#import "SimpleAudioEngine.h"

//preloading is important. do it in the scene init function
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] preloadBackgroundMusic:@"MyBgMusic.caf"];
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] preloadEffect:@"MyEffect.caf"];

//later on
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playBackgroundMusic:@"MyBgMusic.caf"];
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"MyEffect.caf"];
```

Full documentation is here: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.5/interface_simple_audio_engine.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at following book; you will get idea.

[Adding Audio](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/iphone/9781430233039/chapter-4-your-first-game/adding_audio#X2ludGVybmFsX0ZsYXNoUmVhZGVyP3htbGlkPTk3ODE0MzAyMzMwMzkvODk=)